# Vtd xml parsing - filter attributes based on attribute values via xpath

Tags: vtd-xml

I have an xml like below..

```
<keywords>
   <keyword name='Broker1'>
      <value>xxx</value>
   </keyword>
   <keyword name='Broker2'>
      <value>yyy</value>
   </keyword>
</keywords>
```

I want to filter only based on keyword name Broker2. I want to provide the Broker2 attribute value within the xpath like `/keywords/keyword[name='Broker2']`.  Once the filtering is done based on attribute value, i need to extract the value field 'yyy'. I tried Solutions given elsewhere based on `vtdNav.toNormalizedString(autoPilot.evalXpath()` and other approaches. But did not find a solution yet.